# Exchance 2010 catalog files

Tags: exchange

I am running Exchange 2010 at the moment and I have been reviewing space on our Exchange Data drive.   We have four databases sorted by last names so A-F, G-M etc etc but they have 5 to 18 catalog files(.CI) each with dates ranging back to 2013.  Can I delete the older .CI files and keep the most recent?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can safely delete the catalog files.

Refer to the following procedures:

1. Open the Exchange Management Shell and run the following command:

   ```
   Set-MailboxDatabase -Identity databasename -IndexEnabled $false
   ```
2. Stop the service Microsoft Exchange Search Indexer
3. Move the catalog files to the new database location or clean them up
4. Start the service Microsoft Exchange Search Indexer
5. Open the Exchange Management Shell and run the following command:

   ```
   Set-MailboxDatabase -Identity databasename -IndexEnabled $true
   ```

Here is a [similar case](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/545603-exchange-catalog-data-is-it-safe-to-delete-old-ones) for your reference.